# ¿Como calcular el máximo de una sumatoria en SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

Quiero obtener el máximo valor de la sumatoria de los cargos **(Freight)** que pertenecen a cada empleado pero **SQl** no me deja usar una funcion de agregación sobre otra por ejemplo **MAX(SUM(o.Freight))** Mi pregunta es como puedo hacerlo:

**Este es mi código:**

```
USE Northwind     
SELECT e.LastName+' '+e.FirstName as Nombre,  
       SUM(o.Freight) as Cargo  
FROM dbo.Employees e INNER JOIN dbo.Orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID  
GROUP BY e.LastName+' '+e.FirstName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con una subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(Cargo) FROM
(SELECT e.LastName+' '+e.FirstName as Nombre,  
   SUM(o.Freight) as Cargo  
FROM dbo.Employees e INNER JOIN dbo.Orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID  
GROUP BY e.LastName+' '+e.FirstName) AS Sumas
```

Comment: O `Select Top 1 ` junto con `Order By SUM(o.Freight) desc`